# Dynamically chaining Observables in rxjs / angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have a situation where I have multiple events that may be fired from an object.  Those events are handled in a component, and sent to a REST api.  However, I need to ensure that calls to the REST api for a specific resource are sent in series.  So lets say I have the following methods:

```
someObjectCreated(objectCreated){
    this.http.post(...);
}

someObjectNameChanged(objectNameChanged){
    this.http.post(...);
}

someObjectDeleted(objectDeleted){
    this.http.delete(...);
}
```

These event handler methods can be called at anytime.  Lets say I have the scenario where someObjectCreated is called, and then someObjectNameChanged is immediately called after, before the POST of someObjectCreated has returned.

Is there a way I can chain the results from those observables?  Would I better off converting these to promises, and then continually chain them with .then()?  Is there some common pattern used in Angular to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Observable.flatMap` operator.You can achieve it this way.

```
this.service.someObjectCreated(objectCreated)
    .flatMap(objectNameChanged=> this.service.someObjectNameChanged(objectNameChanged))
    .flatMap(secondMethodResult => this.service.someObjectDeleted(secondMethodResult ))
    .subscribe(thirdMethodResult => {
          console.log(thirdMethodResult);
     });
```

Comment: Not correct, it doesn't guarantee that http requests will be sent in order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put loader before any request sent and remove that after complete and update your object as per response, because if you have fired second request with same object before coming first response then you will lose original data.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not related to RxJS, you are right. You can simply chain required actions with promises. You can create some generic function/class for this (no error handling, just giving you an idea):

```
class QueuedActions {

    private currentlyRunning: Promise<void> = Promise.resolve();

    public submit(task: () => Promise<void>): Promise<void> {
       const prevActionPromise = this.currentlyRunning;
       // substitute current promise for next call
       this.currentlyRunning = new Promise<void>(async (resolve, reject) => {
            // wait for previous actions to finish
            await prevActionPromise;
            // perform submitted task
            await task();
            // resolve current promise, so next action can go ahead
            resolve();
        });
        return this.currentlyRunning;
    }

}
```

So you can chain any function returning promise if required:

```
someObjectCreated(objectCreated){
    this.queuedActions.submit(() => this.http.post(...));
}

someObjectNameChanged(objectNameChanged){
    this.queuedActions.submit(() => this.http.post(...));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way chain method `flatMap()`

```
this.service.someObjectCreated(queryParam)
    .flatMap((someObjCreatedRsp) => {
        console.log('someObjCreatedRsp', someObjCreatedRsp);
        return this.service.someObjectNameChanged(queryParam)
    })
    .flatMap((someObjNameChangedRsp) => {
        console.log('someObjNameChangedRsp', someObjNameChangedRsp);
        return this.service.someObjectDeleted(queryParam)
    })
    .subscribe((someObjDeletedRsp) => {
        console.log('someObjDeletedRsp', someObjDeletedRsp);
    });
```